# Get the only failed document response in Bulk API Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am struggling with Bulk API. I am sending 100 request (index, update) in every Bulk request. It gives me response with status of each request. Suppose my 97th request got fail, I have to make it loop to find the particular error document. I think its not optimize way. If i am sending more number of Bulk request, It makes my process slow. Is there any way where i will get only failed document or count of fail/success document in response? I am using `php-elasticsearch` SDK .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for count of fail/success you can use this method:
get count of index before bulk action

you can ignore if if there is no index

```
$parameters = ["index" => "your_index","type" => "your_type"];
$response = $esclient->count($params);
$old_count = $response['count'];
```

use refresh key with true value in parameters that you send as bulk

this refresh this index after performing bulk action

```
$params['refresh'] = true;
$params['body'] = ...;
$total_count = count($params['body']) / 2; //get the total request count
$esclient->bulk($params);
```

after that you can use count method to find out how many index exist

```
$response = $esclient->count($parameters);
$new_count = $response['count'];
```

get the total success

```
$total_success = $new_count - $old_count;
```

get the total failed

```
$total_fail = $total_count- $total_success;
```